# Objective C: Passing NSArray as reference to method

Tags: objective-c, recursion, stack, nsarray, pass-by-reference

I have a method that is passing an array in as reference and I use recursion to call this method over several times. I use the array as a "stack". The code is for a calculator which translates postfix to infix and is just a simple tool.

I have a question regarding the code and its output. The code works but when I uncomment the one section `[stack removeLastObject];` it stops working and claims the array is empty.

I don't get this since I am removing an object from the main array -- not the copies which I am using in the recursion. If I input a copy for recursion and then remove an object from the original is the copy affected?

My main example is using an array of 3, 5, + which should output (3 + 5). If I uncomment the one sections of code I get (3+3). Here is the code:

```
+(NSString*) descriptionTop:(NSMutableArray *) stack{

NSMutableString *programFragment = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@""];

id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
if (topOfStack) [stack removeLastObject];
NSLog(@"operation is %@", topOfStack);
NSLog(@"Stack is%@", stack);


if([ topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]){
    [programFragment appendFormat:@"%g", [topOfStack doubleValue]];
}
else if( [topOfStack isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
{
    NSString *operation = topOfStack;
    if ([operation isEqualToString:@"+"] || 
        [operation isEqualToString:@"-"] ||  
        [operation isEqualToString:@"/"] ||  
        [operation isEqualToString:@"*"]) {

       NSMutableArray *operand1 = [stack mutableCopy];
        [operand1 removeLastObject];

        NSMutableArray *operand2 = [stack mutableCopy];
        // [stack removeLastObject];

        [programFragment appendFormat:@"(%@ %@ %@)", [self descriptionTop:operand1], operation, [self descriptionTop:operand2]];

    }
 }

NSLog(@" program fragment returns %@", programFragment);
return programFragment;
}
```

Comment: Copy's act independently to the source. So, the answer should be No.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to do, but your logic is rather muddled.  Let's walk through your code for the input `[3 5 +]` (where `+` is the top of the stack), assuming your extra `[stack removeLastObject]` is uncommented.  First, you (correctly) pop the operator from the stack:

```
id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
// topOfStack = +
// stack = [3 5 +]

if (topOfStack) [stack removeLastObject];
// topOfStack = +
// stack = [3 5]
```

Then you find that `topOfStack` is a string, so you assign it to `operation`.  Then you do this:

```
        NSMutableArray *operand1 = [stack mutableCopy];
        // operation = +
        // operand1 = [3 5]
        // stack = [3 5]

        [operand1 removeLastObject];
        // operation = +
        // operand1 = [3]
        // stack = [3 5]

        [stack removeLastObject];
        // operation = +
        // operand1 = [3]
        // stack = [3]
```

Notice that at this point, the 5 is gone entirely!  You don't have it in any of your variables.  So when you set up `operand2`, the `3` is on top (and in fact is the only element):

```
        NSMutableArray *operand2 = [stack mutableCopy];
        // operation = +
        // operand1 = [3]
        // stack = [3]
        // operand2 = [3]
```

Now, let's rewind to where we set up `operand1`, but remove the extra `[stack removeLastObject]`:

```
        NSMutableArray *operand1 = [stack mutableCopy];
        // operation = +
        // operand1 = [3 5]
        // stack = [3 5]

        [operand1 removeLastObject];
        // operation = +
        // operand1 = [3]
        // stack = [3 5]

        NSMutableArray *operand2 = [stack mutableCopy];
        // operation = +
        // operand1 = [3]
        // stack = [3 5]
        // operand2 = [3 5]
```

Now `operand2` has `5` at the top, so the recursive call to `descriptionTop:` on `operand2` finds the `5`, and you get a correct answer `(3 + 5)` for `[3 5 +]`.

**But this function is still broken.**

Consider the input `[3 4 5 * +]`.  What's the correct output?  I think it should be `(3 + (4 * 5))`.  But what does your function do?  Let's walk through it.  First, it pops the `+` operator:

```
id topOfStack = [stack lastObject];
// topOfStack = +
// stack = [3 4 5 * +]

if (topOfStack) [stack removeLastObject];
// topOfStack = +
// stack = [3 4 5 *]
```

Next it copies the stack to `operand1` and removes the last element from `operand1`:

```
    NSMutableArray *operand1 = [stack mutableCopy];
    // operation = +
    // operand1 = [3 4 5 *]
    // stack = [3 4 5 *]

    [operand1 removeLastObject];
    // operation = +
    // operand1 = [3 4 5]
    // stack = [3 4 5 *]
```

Then, assuming we don't do `[stack removeLastObject]`, it copies the stack to `operand2`:

```
    NSMutableArray *operand2 = [stack mutableCopy];
    // operation = +
    // operand1 = [3 4 5]
    // stack = [3 4 5 *]
    // operand2 = [3 4 5 *]
```

Now you can see that when we recursively call `descriptionTop:` on `operand1` here, it's going to return `5`.  And when we call recursively call `descriptionTop:` on `operand2`, it's going to return `4 * 5`.  So we return `(5 + (4 * 5))`.  What happened to the `3`?  We never reached it!

The problem here is that, to reach the `3`, we have to *consume* the `4 5 *` from the stack as one operand, and then look for the other operand in *that same stack* (where `4 5 *` has been consumed) so that we can find the `3`.

What you need to do is *not* copy the stack at all!  You need to pass the *same* stack object to your recursive calls, so that when you pop all of the elements that form one operand, you can find the elements for the other operand at the top of the stack.  Like this:

```
    // operation = +
    // stack = [3 4 5 *]

    NSString *operand2Description = [self descriptionTop:stack];
    // operation = +
    // operand2Description = "4 * 5"
    // stack = [3]

    NSString *operand1Description = [self descriptionTop:stack];
    // operation = +
    // operand1Description = "3"
    // operand2Description = "4 * 5"
    // stack = [] (empty stack)

    [programFragment appendFormat:@"(%@ %@ %@)", operand1Description, operation, operand2Description];
    // programFragment = "(3 + (4 * 5))"
```

Comment: This response is amazing and solves everything that I have been having trouble with, I knew that the operands would switch if I kept the code appendformat with the recursion calls in it thats why I used copies but your way is much simpler and works properly, thank you once again for the awesome reply and description

Answer (score 0):

You call `[stack removeLastObject]` twice. When your `stack` array has one element left, the code will fail, because you first you remove last object, and then (if it was `NSString`) you  try to remove last element again, but there are no objects left.

Comment: where would u suggest I put [stack removeLastObject] then?

Comment: im trying to get the stack to be 0 by the end of the method. I dont think it would be called twice since it only goes to [stack removeLastObject] when the value is an operation ie + or -. I am also passing copies when i recursively call it, would it then remove an object from the copy or original stack?

Comment: If the input is checked before processing or input error is handled then there would be not stack with an element type of NSString, as the input will be a postfix expression.